How do I hover in the Tails mech?
On stage 7 (Mission Street) of the Hero Story of Sonic Adventure 2, you play as Tails in a mech. I keep dying on the stage because there are jumps that seem too long for me to make. When I look at videos of the stage, I see they have a hover move to get across. I've tried holding the jump button or tapping it in the air, but the hover won't activate.
Why can't I hover while in the Tails mech? Do I need to unlock the hover?

You'll need to go pick up the hover booster in the stage much like you did with Sonic's light shoes a couple of stages earlier.
Shortly after you get onto the highway part of the stage and fall down the first collapsing road you'll find a right turn to the a gap that's too far to jump, make a left instead and you'll find the upgrade you need.

I'd run across that bridge before it collapsed, so I had progressed past the upgrade without realizing it.
